# Why, in HTML, are you allowed to make a button call a function without wrapping the button in SCRIPT tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering whether someone could explain the logic of this to me. I'm trying to understand HTML and JavaScript as best I can. My understanding was that whenever and only whenever you put something inside JavaScript tags, the browser goes into "JavaScript mode" when it parses what's inside those tags. Hence, having

```
<button onclick="foo()">Click me, bro</button>
```

outside `<script></script>` tags shouldn't work, because everything inside HTML tags is supposed to make sense without JavaScript. I hope someone can clear this up for me.

Comment: [JavaScript in HTML](http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/javascript.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … because everything inside HTML tags is supposed to make sense without JavaScript.

This is an inaccurate conception. The content in event handler attributes of HTML tags, such as `onclick`, is interpreted as Javascript, just as the content of `<script>` tags is.

It is often considered a *best practice* to try to separate Javascript from HTML, but nothing prevents them from being coupled like this.

Answer (score 1):

Some HTML attributes (such as `onclick`, `onload`, etc.) will run the Javascript code that is in it.

For example,

```
<input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="alert('Clicked');" value="Click me">
```

is actually equivalent to (in the `<script>` tags)

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
  alert('Clicked');
}
```

---

If you still do not understand, this is the same as how defining a CSS class in the `<style>` tags

```
.myClass {
  color: Red;
}
```

and then in the `<body>` tags placing the following

```
<a class="myClass">Hello world!</a>
```

is equivalent to (in the `<body>` tags)

```
<a style="color: Red;">Hello world!</a>
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

The following are common events handlers

```
onload //when the page loads
onclick //when a user clicks something
onmouseover //when a user mouses over something
onfocus //when a user puts the cursor in a form field
onblur //When a user leaves a form field
```

They dont need script tags when making calls to JS function from within HTML tags,all of these execute javascript without using a  tag.

For example, while "onclick" can be inserted into most HTML tags to respond to that tag's onclick action.

putting all things together , **EVENTS HANDLERS** are string within an appropriate HTML tag defines a JavaScript function that is invoked by the browser when the appropriate event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely making a logical guess here.

The browser vendors decided it would be a good idea to have attributes attach to event handlers, so the did it, when the page loads the JavaScript engine will find all the elements that have these specific attributes and the will parse them and attach events, so theoretically you can't have JavaScript outside a script tag, but in this case JavaScript engine is specifically finding these attributes obviously by request of the vendor.

It was most probably the coolest thing ever when it came out, now it's just like: *"meh"*

It is recommended by the majority not to use this event attachers